# lightning datatable (AURA or LWC) can automatically fetch records from database?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, datatable, lightning-datatable

Is it possible to fetch records automatically from database just by mentioning columns?

Also can we use relationship fields to get data without any processing?

For example `CreatedBy.Name` ?

Other features like sorting, pagination etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic component which has following features: **(This can be used in both AURA and LWC parent component)**

You can find the component here: https://github.com/sasank-sfdcdev/public/tree/master/src/lwc/datatable

1. Gets data from database automatically. Can use relationship fields also.
2. Sort functionality (across pages)
3. Pagination - first, previous, next and last pages
4. Persistant selection of records across pages. getSelectedRows public method to get selected data.
5. All events of lightning-datatable plus event while loading data
6. Cacheable data
7. Sosl search
8. Dynamically change data filters

---

The simplicity of this is such that, you can just put tag, and rest of the things is done by it. Example HTML:

```
<template>
    <c-datatable config={config}>
    </c-datatable>
</template>
```

and its JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class PocTable extends LightningElement {
    config = {
        objectName: "Account",
        tableConfig: {
            columns: [
                { api: 'Name', label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: true },
                { api: 'CreatedDate', label: 'Created On', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', sortable: true },
                { api: 'CreatedBy.Name', label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'CreatedByName', sortable: true }
            ]
        }
    };
}
```

**NOTE:**  You need add `api` property in `columns` which will be used to fetch data from database.

Here is how it will render:

[image]

---

Here is the sample of AURA component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access = "GLOBAL">

    <aura:attribute name="config" type="Map" default="{}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <c:datatable config="{!v.config}" />

</aura:component>
```

and `controller.js`,

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.config", {
            objectName: "Account",
            tableConfig: {
                columns: [
                    { api: 'Name', label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: true },
                    { api: 'CreatedDate', label: 'Created On', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', sortable: true },
                    { api: 'CreatedBy.Name', label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'CreatedByName', sortable: true }
                ]
            }
        });
    },
})
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the guide :) All these code are quite useful. I fear it will get lost in the question. Do you have a blog which I can follow?

Comment: I have not yet put it in blog. Will create detailed use cases and put it in blog by next week. And yes you are right, I think my question wording might not be correct, or else this comp would be quite useful.

Comment: @salesforce-sas can you share the link of your blog?

Comment: @salesforce-sas Hi,I quoted the plug-in you provided and put it in the LWC program I wrote, but I am now facing a problem. After the first query, everything is normal, but when I query the second time, how to reload your components ? And pass the data of the second query to the component you wrote?