# Passing parameter in getRowActions

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, datatable, action

JS Noob here.
I am currently following lwc datatable [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) to create a datatable with actions. 
The constructor has an argument as 'data' which I want to pass in getRowActions method.

The 'data' param is passed from child class.

How do I access 'data' param in getRowActions method? Also, When I try to access any instance variable in getRowAction using this.variableName, I get reference error.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const actions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
];

const columns = [

];

export default class DatatableExample extends from LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = [];

    constructor(data) {
        super();
        this.columns = [
            // Other column data here
            { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.getRowActions } },
        ]
    }

    getRowActions(row, doneCallback) {
        const actions = [];
            if (row['isActive']) {
                actions.push({
                    'label': 'Deactivate',
                    'iconName': 'utility:block_visitor',
                    'name': 'deactivate'
                });
            } else {
                actions.push({
                    'label': 'Activate',
                    'iconName': 'utility:adduser',
                    'name': 'activate'
                });
            }
            // simulate a trip to the server
            setTimeout(() => {
                doneCallback(actions);
            }), 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To make sure you have access to class variables, bind `this` to the function:

```
{ type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.getRowActions.bind(this) } },
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding more details in addition @sfdcfox answer

You are facing that problem because of lexical scoping. You can use binding (as suggested by @sfdcfox) `RowActions: this.getRowActions.bind(this) }` OR you can simple use arrow function in method:

```
getRowActions = (row, doneCallback) => {
```

---

**NOTE: For automatically fetching records, (no need of implementing sort/data etc)**

You can use [this component](https://github.com/sasank-sfdcdev/public/tree/master/src/lwc/datatable).

You can just implement the table as below:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class PocTable extends LightningElement {
    config = {
        objectName: "Account",
        tableConfig: {
            columns: [
                { api: 'Name', label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: true },
                { api: 'CreatedDate', label: 'Created On', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', sortable: true },
                { api: 'CreatedBy.Name', label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'CreatedByName', sortable: true }
            ]
        }
    };
}
```

and in HTML just pass config:

```
<template>
    <c-datatable config={config}>
    </c-datatable>
</template>
```

Notice the `api` property needed for this. **you do not have to implement your own logic for fetching records from database.**

Refer to [lightning datatable (AURA or LWC) can automatically fetch records from database?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272108/lightning-datatable-aura-or-lwc-can-automatically-fetch-records-from-database)

---